# Toggle Text In One Single State Using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am developing single component toggle module, Currently I am facing one issue. I have populated data in list but in the center of data are populated as per the requirements.

want to show "SHOW" or "HIDE" based on selected button.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const data = [{
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
}, {
    "postId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
}, {
    "postId": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
},];
export default function Test() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState([]);
    console.log('show ==> ', show);
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((item, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <button onClick={() => {
                        if (show[i] === i) {
                            const item = [...show];
                            const final = item.splice(item.indexOf(i), 1)
                            setShow(final);
                        } else {
                            setShow(prev => [...prev, i]);
                        }
                    }}>Toggle</button>
                    {show[i] === i ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'}
                    <hr />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Could you please support me ?

I have created array list state,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const data = [
  {
    postId: 1,
    id: 1,
    name: "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    email: "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    body: "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et",
  },
  {
    postId: 2,
    id: 2,
    name: "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    email: "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    body: "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et",
  },
  {
    postId: 3,
    id: 3,
    name: "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    email: "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    body: "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et",
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState([]);

  const toggleShow = (index) => {
    setShow((prevShow) => {
      const updatedShow = [...prevShow];
      const showIndex = updatedShow.indexOf(index);
      if (showIndex > -1) {
        updatedShow.splice(showIndex, 1); // Hide the item
      } else {
        updatedShow.push(index); // Show the item
      }
      return updatedShow;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <button onClick={() => toggleShow(index)}>
            {show.includes(index) ? "Hide" : "Show"}
          </button>
          {show.includes(index) ? (
            <div>
              <p>Name: {item.name}</p>
              <p>Email: {item.email}</p>
              <p>Body: {item.body}</p>
            </div>
          ) : null}
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]
Let me know, if you've any doubts!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
const [allData, setAllData] = useState(data.map(x => {...x, visible: true });

const toggle = (id: number) => {
  const copy = allData;

  copy.forEach(x => {
    if (x.id === id) {
      x.visible = !x.visible
    } else {
      x.visible = true;
    }
  }

  setAllData(copy)
}

return (
<div>
    {allData.filter(x => x.visible).map((x, i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <p>{x.name}</p>
        <p>{x.email}</p>
        <p>{x.body}</p>
        <button onClick={toggle(x.id)}>{x.visible ? 'Show' : 'Hide' }</button>
      </div>)
    )}
</div>)
```

Comment: It would be append in the list, Not working.
Thanks

Comment: Just so I understand, are you trying to basically just show one of these items at a time? Could you maybe supply a diagram of what it is you are hoping to achieve

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to toggle single of multiple at UI list,
One way to achieve this using HOC component,
But I want one single component.

Comment: New solution added

Answer (score 0):

could you try this way?

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-panini-fvs5d5?file=/src/MyComponent.js:0-1693)

let me know if it is missing what you want

```
import { useState } from "react";

const data = [
  {
    postId: 1,
    id: 1,
    name: "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    email: "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    body:
      "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    postId: 2,
    id: 2,
    name: "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    email: "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    body:
      "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    postId: 3,
    id: 3,
    name: "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    email: "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    body:
      "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  }
];
export const Test = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState([]);
  const handleSelect = (id) => {
    const isHas = show.find((item) => item === id);
    if (isHas) {
      const filtered = show.filter((item) => item !== id);
      setShow(filtered);
    } else {
      setShow([...show, id]);
    }
  };
  const isSelected = (id) => !!show.find((item) => item === id);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <button onClick={() => handleSelect(item?.id)}>
            <span>Toggle</span>
          </button>
          {isSelected(item.id) ? <span>HIde</span> : <span>Show</span>}
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is already answered, I think there is a better way to do this instead of depending on index in the array.

Simply use the state `show` to store the clicked item, and then display the labels based on id.

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState();
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <button onClick={() => setShow(item)}>Toggle</button>
          {show && show.id === item.id ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'}
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```